# Fixing unchecked call to raw type warning Java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code shown below. I'm running into a couple of unchecked warnings from my usage of the Handler raw type in the ingest method. I'm stuck on the best way to remove the warnings and my usage of the raw type. My main stumbling block is the ingest method parameter is IV2GraphObject and any attempt to put a bounds on the Handler gives a compile error when trying to call the handle method on the handler.

```
public class IV2Ingestor implements Ingestor<IV2GraphObject> {
  public interface Handler<T extends IV2GraphObject> {
    void handle(T iv2Object);

    Set<? extends Element> getNewElements();
  }

  // map of handlers for supported objects
  private Map<Class<? extends IV2GraphObject>, Handler<? extends IV2GraphObject>> handlers;

  public static IV2Ingestor getInstance(VisalloEnv environment) {
    // create a new instance
    IV2Ingestor ingestor = new IV2Ingestor();

    ingestor.handlers = new HashMap<>();
    ingestor.handlers.put(Tweet.class, new TweetHandler(graphFactory));
    ingestor.handlers.put(TwitterUser.class, new TwitterUserHandler(graphFactory));
    ingestor.handlers.put(GoogleNews.class, new GoogleNewsHandler(graphFactory));
    ingestor.handlers.put(VKPost.class, new VKPostHandler(graphFactory));
    ingestor.handlers.put(YouTube.class, new YouTubeHandler(graphFactory));
    ingestor.handlers.put(Instagram.class, new InstagramHandler(graphFactory));

    // return ingestor
    return ingestor;
  }

  @Override
  public void ingest(IV2GraphObject ingestable) {
    Class<? extends IV2GraphObject> ingestableClass = ingestable.getClass();

    if (handlers.containsKey(ingestableClass)) {
        Handler handler = handlers.get(ingestableClass);

        try {
            handler.handle(ingestable);
        } finally {
            // persist changes
            graph.flush();

            // notify GPWs of any new graph elements
            workQueueRepository.pushElements(handler.getNewElements(), Priority.LOW);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: why have a `getInstance` rather than constructor? Does not seems to be a singleton.  Why pass (and not use) `VisalloEnv environment` ? what is `graphFactory` ? What are all these classes that you add to `handlers`?  What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to avoid warnings entirely with the given structure. It's just a question of which warning you want and where.

Comment: why would `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` not work?  Although I can not even see how this code would compile

Comment: Your `ingest` method can accept any subtype of `IV2GraphObject`. You then try to pass it to a handler, which only accepts a certain subtype of `IV2GraphObject`. Should rethink your design, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think I answered my own question. I did not want to change the behavior of the ingest method. I wanted it to work the way I defined it to take any type of IV2GraphObject since this is really just internals which I control. I just needed to tweak my handle method definition in the Handler interface. I defined it like the following and was able to remove the SuppressWarning annotation I added. It could be better, I'm certain, but it meets my immediate needs.

<T extends IV2GraphObject> void handle(T iv2Object);

Comment: That change didn't have the desired effect. I opted to suppress the warnings for now until I can rethink this part of the design. It works fine and I'm not too worried about the raw type warnings since the class in question is final.

Comment: You're fighting the compiler. That's an easy way to introduce bugs. Don't try to trick the compiler, it's there to help prevent bugs before runtime. You're shooting yourself in the foot by trying to bypass compiler issues rather than find the right solution to the problem.

Comment: I don't disagree Vince. I have no intention of leaving it this way. I just need to rethink the design. I like the single entry point in the ingest method. My problem is mapping the graph object to the handler responsible for processing it. If anyone has a suggestion I'm listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a map from classes to handlers, where you want each `Class<T>` to be mapped to a `Handler<T>`, but you can't express that relationship with the Map's type. To do this safely, you should make a new class whose API enforces the relationship in the types of arguments and return values of `get` and `put` (the class internally still has an unchecked cast, but the class's API guarantees that this is safe):

```
class ClassToHandler {
    private Map<Class<? extends IV2GraphObject>, Handler<? extends IV2GraphObject>> map
        = HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends IV2GraphObject> Handler<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (Handler<T>)map.get(clazz);
    }

    public <T extends IV2GraphObject> void put(Class<T> clazz, Handler<T> handler) {
        map.put(clazz, handler);
    }
}
```

and you would have `handlers` be an object of this class. This will allow your call to `handlers.get()` to return a better type.

The second problem is that `ingestable.getClass()` returns type `Class<? extends IV2GraphObject>`, which is too loosely connected with the type of `ingestable` (which is `IV2GraphObject`). What you ideally want is `ingestableClass` be `Class<T>` and `ingestable` be `T` for some `T`. That way `handlers.get(ingestableClass)` will return `Handler<T>`, and `handler.handle(ingestable)` will compile.

The reason for the `? extends` in the return type of `.getClass()` is that `ingestable`'s actual runtime class may be a subtype of `IV2GraphObject` (in fact, here, it should always be a subtype), and thus its class is not a `Class<IV2GraphObject>`. However, we know that there exists a type `T` (the actual runtime type of the object), where `ingestable` is an instance of `T` and `ingestable.getClass()` is an instance of `Class<T>`; however, how do we get that `T`? We can use a helper method and capture to get a `T` out of a wildcard `?`:

```
helper(ingestableClass, ...);

private <T extends IV2GraphObject> void helper(Class<T> clazz, ...) { ... }
```

However, even if we do that, the compiler still does not know that `ingestable` is an instance of that same type `T` (we know it must be, but the compiler only knows that `ingestable` is an instance of `IV2GraphObject`). We can use the class's `.cast()` to cast it to the type `T` without any warnings (we know the cast will always succeed, but we do it just to compile with no warnings; we could also have directly done a `(T)` cast which would produce a warning):

```
public void ingest(IV2GraphObject ingestable) {
    Class<? extends IV2GraphObject> ingestableClass = ingestable.getClass();
    helper(ingestableClass, ingestable);
}

private <T extends IV2GraphObject> void helper(Class<T> clazz, IV2GraphObject ingestableTemp) {
    T ingestable = clazz.cast(ingestableTemp);
    Handler<T> handler = handlers.get(ingestableClass);
    try {
        handler.handle(ingestable);
    // ...
}
```